# IE 10 Developer tools changes Document mode back to IE7 standards

Tags: internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools

Recently I was playing around with IE10 Developer Tools, curious about what happens to SO site in IE7 so I changed Browser Mode to IE7 and it turns out that it's not compatible with IE7 and I even can't leave a comment on this mode, so I changed it back to IE10 mode but from then on every time I visit StackOverFlow.com it changes back to "Document Mode: IE7 Standards, Browser Mode: IE10 Compatibility View".
Any idea what's the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes made in the IE10 developer tools don't persist beyond the current browser session.

Based on the symptoms described, you have the site configured to run in Compatibility View, which is a browser setting. Untick the "Broken document" icon in the Address bar, or click Tools > Compatibility View settings and remove the site.

Comment: Oh yes, I was stuck to the developer tools and forgot about the browser itself, I don't know when I did that but that's it thanks a lot.